# How to change Column Collation without losing or changing data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, character-encoding, collation

I have been using mysql version 5.5.41 and have run into an issue. 
I change the collation of a specific column in my table from latin1_swedish_ci to hebrew_bin, and this changes the data in that column. For instance I inserted `école` in the field, and on conversion, I got `?cole`. 
So I searched for a solution and found [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-conversion.html). You can see it states that to not loose data on changing charsets and collations, you must convert to blob and then to the required charset. I tried that too, only to get `יcole`. So how can I change column collations without loosing data.

These were my queries for the blob attempt: -

```
ALTER TABLE `something` CHANGE `name` `name` BLOB;
ALTER TABLE `something` CHANGE `name` `name` VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET hebrew COLLATE hebrew_bin NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Collation has nothing to do with how data is stored. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-general.html

Comment: @user3159519 I edit my answer, check  it

Answer (score 0):

Please do `SELECT HEX(col), col FROM ...` to see what is stored for "école".  Latin1 would look like E9636F6C65.  Hebrew, if I am not mistaken, has not include 'é'.  See http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.hebrew_general_ci.html for what is probably the complete set of characters supported.

Assuming that is correct, do no try to convert to CHARACTER SET hebrew; you will lose information, such as 'é' being turned into '?'.

If you need to store both Hebrew characters and French accented characters (etc), use utf8.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that was very helpful. This means some conversions inevitably change data no matter what. However, I guess now what I mean to know is, how can I know that a particular charset conversion wont change my data. is there an sql query or some php library that can determine that for me as i give it input?

Comment: It sounds like some rows are in latin1, some are in hebrew.  That makes it difficult to fix.  Do you think you can identify which rows are which?